# Simple question - no results (ListView Columns)

Tags: c#, listview, controls

I'm trying to accomplish what should be a very simple task using the ListView Control. All I am trying to do is add two Items to a ListView Control. One Item goes under the "Title" Column and the other Item goes under the "Status" Column. I have seen many examples for the ListView Control and none of them cover this particular need.

I've read the MSDN documentation on the ListView Control and find it rather odd they don't mention this... Or maybe I've overlooked it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ListView parlance, these are not separate items.  It sounds like you want to add one item, and then what ListView calls a subitem.  Assuming that Title is your first column and Status your second, you want:

```
ListViewItem myItem = listView.Items.Add("My Item's Title");
myItem.SubItems.Add("My Item's Status");
```

Comment: Ah, that makes a lotta sense, I completely understand. Thank you so much for your answer! :-) +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are just getting started with a ListView, you can save yourself a *lot* of time, headaches and frustration by using [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) -- an open source wrapper around .NET WinForms ListView.

It solves many problems that you are going to find while trying to use a ListView, as well as just making it much easier to use. Just one example: it automatically handles sorting rows by clicking on column headers.